# Beautifulsoup incomplete table parsing in Python

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a web table using Beautifulsoup and python2.7

The request is ok, but parsing is incomplete.
It seems to stop around 1668 cells no matter the real table lenght.

Here is the code :

```
import os, time, string, operator, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://fse.vdkruijssen.eu/ferrylist.php'

params ={'selectplane':'Cessna 208 Caravan','submit':''}
response=requests.post(url, data=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find(id="ferryplane")
for tr in table.find_all('tr', class_=True):  # filter the row that without text
    row = [cell.text for cell in tr.find_all('td')]
    print(row)
```

How can I retrive all cells?

I'm pretty new to web scraping, any help would be very appreciated

Thank you !

EDIT : Apparently there's no problem with the code. I still get a truncated response as shown (last lines). If you have an idea about what is causing this please tell me !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, time, string, operator, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://fse.vdkruijssen.eu/ferrylist.php'

params ={'selectplane':'Cessna 208 Caravan','submit':''}
response=requests.post(url, data=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find(id="ferryplane")
for tr in table.find_all('tr', class_=True):  # filter the row that without text
    row = [cell.text for cell in tr.find_all('td')]
    print(row)
```

out:

```
['HB-TCK', 'Badenflug (carbonex)', 'LSZS', 'LSMU', '67', '1000', '670', '348', '419']
['RPC-3255', 'Bank of FSE', 'WAMR', 'RPLV', '910', '110', '1001', '-3374', '-2405']
['I-FGTY', 'Bank of FSE', 'LGEL', 'LIBN', '284', '110', '312', '-1428', '-925']
['ZT-YMC', 'Bank of FSE', 'FLEB', 'FAUT', '1230', '110', '1353', '-4560', '-3251']
['CS-PRB', 'PRA Rentals (Matt74)', 'LZKZ', 'EDDK', '561', '175', '982', '-1908', '-1180']
['ZU-YTU', 'Bank of FSE', 'FABE', 'FAJS', '409', '110', '450', '-2008', '-1300']
['ZS-FXN', 'cckohrs', 'FYML', 'FALA', '548', '200', '1096', '-2668', '-1377']
['HL-7227', 'Bank of FSE', 'RJOB', 'RKSO', '360', '110', '396', '-1483', '-971']
```

I am sure no row is missing:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this gives me the same result: Last output is truncated, and the end of the table is missing

Comment: @MagicP which row is missing?

Comment: @MagicP check my screenshot

Comment: don't get it... check mine

Comment: @MagicP I tested my code both in python2 and python3. I post the full code, you can paste and run it

Comment: Thank you... with your code it still gives me a truncated response on my computer

Comment: @MagicP there is nothing I can do about it